# CSS Selector: select element based on last parent with specific class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some classes that apply background color to divs:

```
.bg-light: white;
.surface-light: light-gray;

.bg-dark: black;
.surface-dark: darker-gray;
```

The problem is when I am trying to apply custom colors to elements inside these divs, such as texts, buttons, borders, etc. I am trying to do like this:

```
.bg-light input,
.surface-light input {
    color: black;
}

.bg-dark input,
.surface-dark input {
    color: white;
}
```

But it don't work in scenarios like this:

```
light:
  dark:
    light:
        other-classes...: input
```

because the input selection will be true in both cases, and will set the last color defined. So I need to make a selection to considerate only the last 'ascendent' parent.

Any ideas? thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want to only consider the immediate parent of the input element ?

Comment: No, because in some cases I will have extra divs between the div and input... like that: div.surface-light > form > div.form-control > input ... So I will need to find which is closest to the input, if is a div.surface-light or div.surface-dark, for exemple.

Comment: Try to use the inherit keyword as the color property value. Set the same color rule you want for the input element for the background div too and then set color: inherit for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it using variables:

```
.bg-light {
  background-color: var(--clr-bg-light);
}
.surface-light {
  background-color: var(--clr-surface-light);
}
.bg-light, .surface-light {
  --clr-text: var(--clr-text-dark);
  --clr-neutral: var(--clr-neutral-dark);
}

.bg-dark {
  background-color: var(--clr-bg-dark);
}
.surface-dark {
  background-color: var(--clr-surface-dark);
}
.bg-dark, .surface-dark {
  --clr-text: var(--clr-text-light);
  --clr-neutral: var(--clr-neutral-light);
}

.text { color: var(--clr-text); }
.neutral { color: var(--clr-neutral); }
```